# What are best practices/methods in preventing ajax requests and or form submisions from pages that my server did not serve?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security

Knowing that anyone can see my AJAX URL string and or forms how can I prevent calls or submissions from pages that my server did not serve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verifying the source of the form submission is best done by using cookies/sessions. Authenticating each request is your best protection against such cross-site attacks.

Comment: if you could give a little more explanation (a small illustration if possible), it would be great and helpful to many.

Comment: @sandeepan: not without any knowledge of the language of implementation. remember, validation is done server-side.

Comment: how exactly using cookies/sessions?

Comment: See this PHP implementation: http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries